# Display mode of Word document generated in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I want to export a page to a .doc file but when I open the generated .doc it opens in weblayout-view instead of print-view. This is ugly and confusing. Is there a way to set it to print-view?

The script I use to generate the doc:

```
<?php  if(isset($_GET['word'])) {
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=test.doc");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style type="text/css"> /* SOME STYLING */ </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello StackOverflow!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And now that i'm here is it possible to add word-checkboxes ☒ and word-input fields?

Comment: You realise that you're not actually creating a word document.... this is HTML markup with headers to pretend it's a Word document, which MS Word is generous enough to open; that's why it opens it in web layout view, because it is a web document.

Comment: then what is the proper way to export html to a doc?

Comment: The proper way is to generate an actual doc file (either BIFF or OfficeOpenXML)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=FILENAME.doc"); 
?>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 9">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 9">
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<title>title</title>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Print</w:View>
  <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>
  <w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>
  <w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>
 </w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]-->
<style>
</head>
<body>
  Yes printview!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is only one more problem... "Save as" default is "Save as webpage" instead of .doc(x)