# How to export dynamic html table to doc file using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new using PHP and I need a bit of help here.

I'd like to send a HTML table to another PHP file, and then, be to able to use this information (specifically I want to download this like DOC file).

I've seen a lot of information how to do it. But I haven't seen how to do without `<tbody></tbody>`. I have a dynamic table, so, the data is loading from an array. By the way, I'm using DataTable-jQuery to do it.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form action="sectoresTable.php" method="post"> 
    <table id="sectoresTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>#</b></th>
                <th><b>Numero</b></th>
                <th><b>Nombre</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px;">Exportar</button>
</form>
```

and `sectoresTable.PHP`:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TablaSectores.doc"); 

    echo '';
?>
```

By the way, to load the data into the table, I'm using the following script:

```
<script>
    $('#sectoresTable').DataTable({
        data: arraySectores
    });
</script>
```

In general all this is working good, I download a doc file but without information (and That is right because my echo is printing nothing.).

I understand that I need to use a foreach in my HTML code? But really, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this all the code you have or is there more ?

Comment: This answer might help:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/11536958/3044080

Comment: yes, It's all... to load the data in the table, I have a script in javascript. It's very simple: $('#sectoresTable').DataTable({data: arraySectores});

Answer (score 1):

try to use an api,to export dynamic html table to doc file in php

```
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2763-PHP-Convert-HTML-into-Microsoft-Word-documents.html
```